# Routing network to elastic IP in AWS to my laptop

Tags: amazon-web-services, nvidia, amazon-vpc

I was wondering weather in any world following scenarios is possible
I setup IPSEC Tunnel from my VPC to my home network and via some method I redirect network coming to my elastic IP address to my laptop that is connected to my home network

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to accomplish this? If you can explain your high-level use-case, we might be able to offer a better alternative. Are you merely wanting to have your laptop appear to have different IP addresses? Is this for web-scraping purposes?

Comment: The reason is: i need to stream game from my laptop over internet (using NVIDIA MOONLIGHT STREAM), and i cant move it to cloud, as it seems cloud doesnt have supporting GPU drivers yet. and my ISP is not giving me public IP